# Highlight parent and child navigation menu when active or current

Tags: html, css, highlight

Would someone show me how to highligh parent and child navigation menu when active or current. Is it possible to highlight the parent menu item when a child page is selected. what i am trying to achieve is something like http://www.brotfabrik-berlin.de/ when you hover to a subpage the parent keeps being highlighted. Thank you.

```
#menu {
font-weight:700;
list-style:none;
width:990px;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
height:29px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;

/* Rounded Corners */

-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;

/* Background color and gradients */

background: #014464;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #, #);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#), to(#));

/* Borders */

border: 1px solid #002232;

-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;

#menu li {
float:left;
display:block;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:0px;
border:none;
z-index: 1;

#menu li:hover {
border: 1px solid #777777;
padding: 2px 4px 4px 4px;

/* Background color and gradients */

background: #F4F4F4;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));

/* Rounded corners */

-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

#menu li a {
font-family:Arial Narrow;
font-size:15px; 
color: #EEEEEE;
display:block;
outline:0;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;

#menu li:hover a {
color:#161616;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
```

Comment: Did you look at your question in the preview before clicking "Post"? Or afterward when it showed after posting? It doesn't take much time to glance at the **How to Format** box on the right when you're posting. (And you can edit your question when you realize you need to.) (**Edit**: Kush was kind enough to fix it for you, then I approved the edit; looks like it's not even valid CSS.) Separately: What did you try? Where are you stuck? Just throwing a bunch of CSS at the site and saying you want to know how to do it doesn't show much effort.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but it is my understanding that new code does not need vendor-specific `-moz-` and `-webkit-` anymore if there is already a standard that exists? 

Any reasons to keep using vendor-specific tags?

Comment: @kush: It completely depends on the property, and the target browser support.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually achieve this by adding a `current` class to the `<li>` of the navigation link. So if you are viewing `home.html` the navigation code would be like so:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I would style the current class by using the hover style of the link, or you could define a different style, for example:

```
#menu li.current a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If the `<li>` contains a sub menu (another `<ul>`), I would target the CSS like this:

```
#menu > li > a {
    /* this would target the parent link */
}
```

And to target submenu links I would do:

```
#menu ul ul a {
    /* this would target submenu links */
}
```